# Not compelete result from Azure speech to text API

Tags: c#, azure, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I have a small wav sound file in which I want to get the text of it, so I used Azure speech to text API to test it.
first thing I convert the audio file as they recommended in their documentation to PCM - Mono -16K sample rate.
and I use this code in c# in the documentation example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/getstarted/getstartedrest?tabs=CSharp) to upload the file and get the result.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = null;
    request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://speech.platform.bing.com/speech/recognition/interactive/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=detailed");
    request.SendChunked = true;
    request.Accept = @"application/json;text/xml";
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
    request.ContentType = @"audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000";
    request.Headers["Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key"] = "my key";

    // Send an audio file by 1024 byte chunks
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:/b.wav", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {

        /*
        * Open a request stream and write 1024 byte chunks in the stream one at a time.
        */
        byte[] buffer = null;
        int bytesRead = 0;
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            /*
            * Read 1024 raw bytes from the input audio file.
            */
            buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(1024, (int)fs.Length))];
            while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            {
                requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            // Flush
            requestStream.Flush();
        }
    }
    string responseString;
    Console.WriteLine("Response:");
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(responseString);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

also i tried using cUrl tool and also write it in java as i was thought that maybe it's problem with the programming language I use that i not upload the file correctly.
this the link of the sound file i want to convert it to text [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MdpT_tEB-OaOsg1XY3IzEVzG0sZ3GDdp).
so Now i need to help to figure it out if the problem comes from the format of the sound file? or from maybe code that i not upload it correctly? or it's from the API I mean to be not accurate enough?
i tried IBM speech to text and it got all the text with no problem.
iam using now the free trial of Azure speech to text API and I want to figure where the problem comes if anyone has experience with this to see if I will work with this API or not.
**Update**
I want to clear that iam not got any error i just got incomplete result to my sound file I upload, for example the sound file i upload he said at the end of the sound `"What is up with that"`, the result i got from Azure is just the first sentence only which is `"I say that like it's a bad thing."`, also I upload another sound file which contains the `"What is up with that"` only check it [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/123Y9qee26yb84kxG5zZdibp1EOrwEraO/view),and it just gives me an empty result like this.

```
{"RecognitionStatus":"NoMatch","Offset":17300000,"Duration":0}
```

so all that i want to know if this normal from the Speech to text API Azure or the problem with my code or from the sound file? this what i want to get an answer with it.
when i test another API on those files it worked like IBM for example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is not related to "Azure API Management" which is a separate service in azure. It would help if you describe what error you're actually getting.

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin I updated the question with my problem so please if you can confirm this in answer to me if the problem from Azure or the File?, or it's in my code but I don't think so because I use the same code on the website of the Azure API and use the same format as the file in which is already accepted by the API and give me the result.
so if you can tell me please if the problem is from the API or not

Comment: Not really sure on the error. Try adding "azure-cognitive-services" tag to get correct exposure for the question.